# How to Clone A UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView and I want to make a copy of it and place it somewhere on the screen. How do I do this?

I currently only know how to copy and paste the image manually and make a separate IBOutlet for each one, but this is very inefficient because I want to make a game that generates obstacles (UIImageViews) forever so I can't do it the manual way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make sure you match all of the properties up as well, like size, clipping, image aspect, opacity, etc.

```
CGPoint locationOfCloneImageView = CGPointMake(0, 0);//x and y coordinates of where you want your image. (More specifically, the x and y coordinated of where you want the CENTER of your image to be)

UIImageView *cloneImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImageView.image];
cloneImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImageView.frame.size.width, originalImageView.frame.size.height);//same size as old image view
cloneImageView.alpha = originalImageView.alpha;//same view opacity
cloneImageView.layer.opacity = originalImageView.layer.opacity;//same layer opacity
cloneImageView.clipsToBounds = originalImageView.clipsToBounds;//same clipping settings
cloneImageView.backgroundColor = originalImageView.backgroundColor;//same BG color
cloneImageView.tintColor = originalImageView.tintColor;//matches tint color.
cloneImageView.contentMode = originalImageView.contentMode;//matches up things like aspectFill and stuff.
cloneImageView.highlighted = originalImageView.highlighted;//matches whether it's highlighted or not
cloneImageView.opaque = originalImageView.opaque;//matches can-be-opaque BOOL
cloneImageView.userInteractionEnabled = originalImageView.userInteractionEnabled;//touches are detected or not
cloneImageView.multipleTouchEnabled = originalImageView.multipleTouchEnabled;//multi-touches are detected or not
cloneImageView.autoresizesSubviews = originalImageView.autoresizesSubviews;//matches whether or not subviews resize upon bounds change of image view.
//cloneImageView.hidden = originalImageView.hidden;//commented out because you probably never need this one haha... But if the first one is hidden, so is this clone (if uncommented)
cloneImageView.layer.zPosition = originalImageView.layer.zPosition+1;//places it above other views in the parent view and above the original image. You can also just use `insertSubview: aboveSubview:` in code below to achieve this.
[originalImageView.superview addSubview:cloneImageView];//adds this image view to the same parent view that the other image view is in.

cloneImageView.center = locationOfCloneImageView;//set at start of code.
```

Comment: Your answer does seem to be more complete. I was just wondering: is there a way to affect my originalImageView and all my cloned images? For example animate them all at the same time?

Comment: Yes! Give each imageView a tag... `cloneImageView1.tag = 128001`, `cloneImageView2.tag = 128002`, `cloneImageView1.tag = 128003`, `cloneImageView1.tag = 128004`, then use a while loop with `int i = 1;`, `while (i <= numberOfImagesYouHave) {, and `i++;` .. each time in the loop say `UIImageView *viewToAnimate = (UIImageView *)[originalImageView.superview viewWithTag:i];` then apply your animation code to `viewToAnimate`, it will loop through the whole image set (using tags) and apply it to every imageView.

Comment: @Andrew, post your animation code and image cloning code and I'd be happy to modify the code for you if I'm online by the time you do it :)

Comment: Alternatively, if your animation is already set on the originalImage BEFORE you start cloning, then while you clone you could just say things like `cloneImageView.animationImages = originalImageView.animationImages;` and `cloneImageView.animationDuration = originalImageView.animationDuration;` and `cloneImageView.animationRepeatCount = originalImageView.animationRepeatCount;` and `[cloneImageView startAnimating];`

Comment: Oh, if you are using the tags I just thought of an even better approach so you don't have to give a different tag to each one (although it will be a little slower but that's unnoticeable) ... you could use a for loop and say `for (UIView *anyView in [originalImageView.superview subviews]) {` and `if (anyView.tag == /*whatever number you decide to set*/) {` and then cast UIImageView type using `anyView = (UIImageView *)anyView;` and then, inside the for-loop, run your animation code on `anyView`.

Comment: And then you can just say `cloneImageView.tag = originalImageView.tag;` when you clone... but make sure before you clone you do give `originalImageView` a unique tag integer!

Comment: what about constraints?

Comment: @John Yes if you are using constraints you want to do that as well. I personally don't use them but I am aware that I'm in the minority these days for that haha.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create one new `UIImageView` with its new frame where you want to place it. set its image property of your existing imageView's image, and after that add it to your view.

```
UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
newImageView.image = oldImageView.image;
[self.view addSubView:newImageView]
```

Comment: Try adding in a for loop, to change it up a little. Like so: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 10,0,50,50)];
newImageView.image = oldImageView.image;
[self.view addSubView:newImageView] }

Comment: @brimizer Why For loop, OP just want 1 copy. And even if he wants he can do the same.

Comment: Worked great. Much more simple than I thought it would be. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew, this code is incomplete and won't match things like imageView size and other properties like opacity, whether the image is aspectFill or thing like that... It also just assumes your image is in self.view rather than figuring out which view is the parent view of your original image. Please check out my in-depth answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25439317/2057171

Comment: @YogeshSuthar OP said " I want to make a game that generates obstacles (UIImageViews) forever so I can't do it the manual way." So I just wanted to illustrate that a bunch of image views could be generated at once. It wasn't a suggestion to improve your answer, just an additional comment :)